# How i can dynamic my flash message in angular. message must be coming through API response

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

My flash message code is below

```
<div class="flash-message" ng-if="flash">
<div class="{{'alert alert-' + flash.type}}" ng-bind="flash.message"> 
</div>
```

Right now i am using

```
  FlashService.Success('You have blocked this User');
```

I want to make my above message dynamic, i have passed static right now.

My node api is return this message right now

```
{
"data": {
    "status": "1",
    "msg": "You have blocked the user"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the result in function callback.

```
{
"data": {
"status": "1",
"msg": "You have blocked the user"
}
}
```

Put the below code to make flash Message dynamic.

```
   FlashService.Success(result.data.msg);
```

Comment: Thanks it saved my day.

Comment: and use ng-class instead of class